# Service account storage limit

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-drive-api

I want to increase my 15GB storage limit per service account on google drive storage to a much higher number. how could it be done?
Currently, I'm getting a 'The user has exceeded their Drive storage quota' HttpError 403

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly advise you to explore the possibility of making user impersonation.

In case you are working with a Google Workspace account you could review the steps about how to make user impersonation here:
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#java

Here is another example: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation#python

Answer (score 0):

Each Google Account comes with 15 GB of shared storage (Gmail, Drive, Photos).

To increase your storage quota, upgrade to Google One.

[Google One Plans and Pricing](https://one.google.com/about/plans)

Comment: It’s a GCP service account, I can’t log in and purchase more storage like a normal google account

Comment: @LiorPaz The error comes from Google Drive and not Google Cloud. Google Cloud Storage does not have limits as described in your question. Every user can create nearly unlimited storage.